# Git LFS accidental migration "corrupted" my java files

Tags: git-lfs

I wanted to upload a project to GitHub to share with my laptop, there was a 500mb file in the project. I added git lfs to push the big file aswell , accidently made every file into an lfs file. Now all my java files look like this
[image]